# Show path of file from where the code autocompletion is coming from

Tags: autocompletion

When doing auto completion with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, I see autocompletion suggestions from the current file as well as from different other files all mixed together as seen below:

[image]

I would like to get a behavior similar to what is shown on the below picture, i.e. display the path of the file containing the suggestion if the suggestion is coming from file other than the current one.

[image]

Comment: Where is the image from ?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble from this video in the autocompletion section: https://youtu.be/XA2WjJbmmoM

Comment: Perhaps this is related to the version of Vim... Which version are you using? I just tested this on 8.2.1704 and I see the behavior that includes the filenames... But I do recall seeing the menu without any filenames in the past, so it's possible that this was a somewhat recent addition.

Comment: I'm using version `8.2.2200` which is even more recent. Also, the video dates back to 2016.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to available space in the menu? If the file names are too long? In `:ls` output, do you see relative paths or absolute ones?

Comment: @filbranden I see relative paths with `ls`.

Comment: Perhaps post a screenshot of what you see instead?

Comment: I edited the question with a screenshot of the currently observed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it work if you have your file opened as buffer in vim. The autocompletion will look at them when you launch `CTRL_P` or `CTRL_N` (see `:help complete`):

```
'complete' 'cpt'        string  (default: ".,w,b,u,t,i")
                        local to buffer
        This option specifies how keyword completion ins-completion works
        when CTRL-P or CTRL-N are used.  It is also used for whole-line
        completion i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L.  It indicates the type of completion
        and the places to scan.  It is a comma separated list of flags:
        .       scan the current buffer ('wrapscan' is ignored)
        w       scan buffers from other windows
        b       scan other loaded buffers that are in the buffer list
        u       scan the unloaded buffers that are in the buffer list 
        U       scan the buffers that are not in the buffer list
        k       scan the files given with the 'dictionary' option
        kspell  use the currently active spell checking spell
        k{dict} scan the file {dict}.  Several "k" flags can be given,
                patterns are valid too.  For example:
                        :set cpt=k/usr/dict/*,k~/spanish
        s       scan the files given with the 'thesaurus' option
        s{tsr}  scan the file {tsr}.  Several "s" flags can be given, patterns
                are valid too.
        i       scan current and included files
        d       scan current and included files for defined name or macro
                i_CTRL-X_CTRL-D
        ]       tag completion
        t       same as "]"
```

Comment: The question is not about just completing from keywords found in other buffers... But about listing the name of the file/buffer where that keyword is coming from. See the screenshot, the right column lists file paths (`lib/tella.rb` and `lib/tella/server/tcp.rb` for the three first keywords.)

Comment: @filbranden this is strange.  Normally it works without any specific configuration. I also tried it with an empty vimrc and the classic vi editor and the name of the file/buffer appeared like in your screenshot. I was wondering if you might have changed a setting by accident. That's why I give you this response. But if your vimrc is clean, thats a mystery. I will try to see another solution, but there is no guarantee that I will find one.

Comment: Just tried on macOS with version `8.2.2200` and on Ubuntu with version `8.2.1897` with an empty `.vimrc` and I don't observe the desired behavior.

Comment: I can confirm @FabriceHategekimana's comment: it _should_ show filenames beside the completion entry. It shows on both my nvim 8.0 and vim 8.1. Both with `--clean`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the built-in `:help ins-completion`, I can only think of two reasons why the name of the buffer where the suggestion comes from is not displayed:

- The buffer is unnamed.
- The keyword is also present in the current buffer.

In the screenshot below, taken in `$ vim -Nu NONE`, `foo` doesn't get a bufname because it is already in the current buffer, `football` and `foobar` both get a bufname because they are from buffer `foo` (naming is hard), and `icare` doesn't get a bufname because it is from an unnamed buffer.

[image: demo]